# How to get last 4 inserted ID's in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get the last 4 inserted ID's from a database table, which should basically get the 4 latest / most recently added fields.

I know there is a `lastInsertId()` function in PHP which gets the last one.

For example if I have the last inserted ID stored to a variable like this:

```
$productID = $db->lastInsertId();
```

But how do I get last 4 inserted ID's rather than just the last one?

Is there a quick way around this?

Assuming there is an ID and it is the primary key for each record.

**Edit**

My ID fields are auto increment as I forgot to mention previously

Comment: If it is primary key and set as auto_increment the do `select id from table order by id desc limit 4`

Comment: Have you tried using SQL or am I missing something here ?

Comment: @Jack No this script only retrieves the last 4 inserted ID's another script inserts the records one at a time

Comment: Use an automated timestamp.

Comment: Be careful when ask question here add full details like your last edit shows without this information you can see the mess of downvotes got the peoples who tried to help you  -1  for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select WHATEVER_FIELDS from TABLE order by IDFIELD desc limit 4`

Comment: I'd still want to know what is wrong with my answer.

Comment: Why would you even `select *`?

Comment: select whatever you want... use brain and what u need

Comment: Why did he got a down vote? the logic is good, dont know whats with SO these days but its starting to be full with arrogant people, and everybody wants full comőplete code...., gave you an up vote

Comment: Still not correct. OP never said the IDs are autoincrement, only that they are primary. Last 4 IDs inserted doesn't necessarily mean they are the highest values.

Comment: @LeventeNagy I certainly agree with your last statement, SO has seemed to form a jurisdiction... I gave an upvote too

Comment: @RichardRodriguez Please tell me what does an order by has to do if its something is auto increment or not? if its auto increment or not still get the same result

Comment: @LeventeNagy: the fact that the last 4 inserted ids may be 'XXC3', 'AA33', '8831' AND 'c1'. You don't get those values with the query in this answer.

Comment: @RichardRodriguez OP mentioned they *are* in fact AI :) but you had a good point nonetheless :)

Comment: @RichardRodriguez if i must i will make you a working example that it does work and not difference with this query.... want it?.... just to break your horn down....

Comment: @LeventeNagy: no, thanks, keep your wrong information to yourself

Answer (score 0):

[MYSQL: LAST_INSERT_ID FUNCTION](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/last_insert_id.php)

I will just bring here some of the notes mentioned there

- If the most recent INSERT or UPDATE statement set more than one AUTO_INCREMENT value, the LAST_INSERT_ID function returns only the first AUTO_INCREMENT value.
- The LAST_INSERT_ID function returns the last AUTO_INCREMENT value on a client-by-client basis, so it will only return the last AUTO_INCREMENT value for your client. The value can not be affected by other clients.
- Executing the LAST_INSERT_ID function does not affect the value that LAST_INSERT_ID returns.

So in order to retrieve last 4 Inserted IDs you must check the id for EACH insert/update you are doing.

Selecting last 4 rows is not an option - consider this:
 * person A inserts row with autoid 1
 * person B inserts row with autoid 2
 * person A inserts row with autoid 3,4
 * person B inserts row with autoid 5
 * person A inserts row with autoid 6

If you are person A and after each insert you check the **last inserted id** you will get: `1, 3, 4, 6`  if you are person B you will get `2, 5`
If you are person A and use that query for selecting you will get `3,4,5,6`

And one more - if your rows have not autoincremented ID, here is something im doing:

- add column with index (char 32)
- on insert fill that column with some data (unique);
- after inserting - SELECT row where column is that data
- update row column to null (its not needed now)

Answer (score -1):

There is only **1** last inserted ID and that is after every query which makes an insert. `lastInsertId()` therefore returns that ID and you call it after the insert has been made.

That means you have to call `lastInsertId()` 4 times, after every insert query and store its result in an array.

**EDIT**: I understand that last 4 IDs can be queried with SELECT, but that is not what the OP is asking. If OP wants the last 4 IDs in the DB, not the last 4 IDs inserted, the question should be formed in a completely different way.

Comment: Wow, that downvote was pretty quick. Less than 1 second after I posted the answer. Good job, stack overflow!

Comment: A guess for the downvotes: the asker is using PDO (`lastInsertId()`). However, your information is correct in that you'd have to call lastInsertId() after each successful insertion.

Comment: @RichardRodriguez No I clearly said in the question I want last 4 inserted ID's

Comment: @user3574492: yes, that's my point. ``last 4 inserted`` does not equal to ``last 4``. the answer you currently accepted returns ``last 4``. that's a totally different thing. you would disambiguate this situation if you claimed right away that your column is auto-incremented.

Comment: I haven't accepted any answer yet.. But if the fields are AI then won't the last 4 always be the last inserted?

Comment: Yes, if they are AI, then the top answer is correct.